# « ... , dites-moi ! » ou « ... , dis-moi ! » placé à la fin d’une phrase

Tags: expressions

> 1 : Vous avez l’air de les connaître comme votre poche, **dites-moi** ! {d’un ton de reproche}
>
> 2 : Oh, mais ton ami est tout à fait charmant, **dis-moi** !

Je me demande ce que veut dire cette expression, au juste ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cette locution est ici très similaire à *dites-donc* / *dis-donc*.

Elle est utilisée à l'oral pour attirer l'attention, exprimer ses sentiments sur ce que l'on dit par ailleurs et, plus que *dis-donc*, pour inviter son interlocuteur à le commenter.

Comment: Hi. Having a look at a picture of your friend, you say: « Mais, **dis donc**, Albert, c'est toi, ça ? Tu as l’air si jeune. » In this instance, you are obviously expecting some response from your friend. So can you also say: « Mais, **dis-moi**, Albert, c'est toi, ça ? »

Comment: Yes, you can definitely say it.